# Сумма с формы заявки на почту

Tags: javascript, html

Есть функция отправки значений селектора на почту. 
Не могу дописать последнюю строчку(`hidden2.value=span`), чтобы отправлялось значение `span` из `final_price`:

```
<span id="final_price">6300</span> Руб.
<input type='hidden' name='Стоимость' id='hidden2'/>

function PutToHidden()
{
  var hidden;
  var hidden2;
  var select;
  var span;

  select=document.getElementById('select');
  hidden=document.getElementById('hidden');
  span=document.getElementById('final_price');
  hidden2=document.getElementById('hidden2');

  hidden.value=select.options[select.selectedIndex].text;
  hidden2.value=span;
}
```

Comment: так а что вообще должно быть в последней строчке?

Comment: значение `span` или текст из `span` ?

Comment: Забыла дописать в html коде:  <span id="final_price">6300</span> Руб.
               <input type='hidden' name='Стоимость' id='hidden2'/> Значение которое выводится в final_price мне нужно отправлять на почту

Comment: значения select, chekbox приходят на почту,а сумма не отображается

Comment: нужно значение span

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте [innerText](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText) или [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)

Т.е.: `hidden2.value=span.textContent;`

```js
let span=document.getElementById('final_price');
let hidden2=document.getElementById('hidden2');
hidden2.value=span.textContent;
```

```html
<span id="final_price">6300</span> Руб. 
<input type='text' name='Стоимость' id='hidden2'/>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!!!все работает!!!!